# How to retrieve Raphael object id on the click /hover when objects are stored in an array

Tags: jquery, raphael

```
var shapes = new Array();
var kx=50,ky=150;
var RecWidth=120;
var RecHeight=85;
var RecRadius=10;

r = Raphael(10,10, '60%', '100%');

for (var i=0; i<= 10; i++) {

 shapes[i]=r.rect(kx, ky, RecWidth, RecHeight,RecRadius);

 shapes[i].id="keylist"+i ;

 kx=kx+50;

 ky=ky+150;

}
```

above code will generate 10 Raphael rect on the page with different id's. Now i want to retrieve the id i.e keylist on the mouse click or hover event,so that based on the Keylist i want to show a popup with more information related to this key list.

my problem is that i don't know how to retrieve Raphael object id on the click /hover when objects are stored in an array like here array is Shapes ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could define a `click` or `hover` event handler like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<= 10; i++) {    
 shapes[i]=r.rect(kx, ky, RecWidth, RecHeight,RecRadius);    
 shapes[i].id="keylist"+i;
 shapes[i].click(handleClick);
 shapes[i].hover(handleHoverIn, handleHoverOut);
 kx=kx+50;    
 ky=ky+150;    
}

function handleClick() {
    var id = this.id; // get your id
    // do something with your id    

}

// mouse enters the rectangle
function handleHoverIn() {
    var id = this.id; // get your id
    // do something with your id    

}

// mouse leaves the rectangle
function handleHoverOut() {
    var id = this.id; // get your id
    // do something with your id    

}
```

UPDATE:

Maybe this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75Mwk/) will help.

Comment: i stuck again on this for a little different case. here when i mouse hover on "More Information" then i am getting error and so unable to get shapes id and its coordinate. i need this because i want to attach a popup on the shapes to dispaly some additional information. here is my Js Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jdev/Mj5R3/10/

Comment: Hi, you try to use 'i' in your callback functions (hoverIn and hoverOut), but those functions will be called after you exited your for-loop, so there is no 'i' anymore (for more information: http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62). What you can do is: save your 'i' in your 'id' property of the raphael text element, then you can easily retrieve it. JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E7nm4/

Comment: PS: You shouldn't have UNACCEPTED my answer, because I've answered your first question correct and you ACCEPTED it. If you have a new problem you can easily create a new question and maybe add a link to your old question, if needed.

Comment: i agree with you. sorry, since i am new to this forum, i don't know how to handle this. i unaccepted answer so that re-use this question. next time i will make sure, that i create a new question.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the solution and for the article as well.